# How to Share common shared library amoung multiple APKs to reduce size

Tags: android, linux, shared-libraries, apk

I have one big shared library (.so file) written in C++. How can share it among multiple APKs without bundling it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use by defining the library in `build.gradle` you want to use :

```
implementation project(':core')
implementation project(path: ':commons:ui')
implementation project(path: ':commons:views')
```

These are my modules and to use them in app module the above code is being used

[image: Modules]